# Can I use Creality bed on Prusa MK3S?

Tags: prusa-i3

I need a Prusa MK3S smooth bed and I am not able to get it unless I wait for a few month.

But I can have a `Heated Bed Cover for Ender 3/Ender 3 pro/Ender 5 3D Printer 235X235MM` shipped to my door tomorrow moring.

Can I use the above Creality bed on MK3S untill I get an original MK3S in a few month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Heaters won't match.

The ender3 is a 24 V machine. The Prusa 3 is a 12 V machine. Heater cartridges and Heatbeds are therefore not interchangeable.

## Build surfaces can be adapted.

The Ender3 has a build surface that is a little bigger than the Prusa3, and thus you can, in a pinch, use an ender3 sized build surface and install it, possibly cut down, to fit onto the Prusa.